# Fourier transform on Schwartz Space is a continous automorphism

Tags: fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I am currently trying to understand the Fouriertransform of Schwartz functions. There are two proofs I'm trying to figure out.

1. $\mathcal{F}$ is a continous operator $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$.
2. $\mathcal{F}$ is a automorphism on $\mathcal{S}( \mathbb R)$.

At first we prove, that $\forall f \in \mathcal{S}( \mathbb R) :\widehat f \in  \mathcal{S}( \mathbb R)$.

> This proof is a use of the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma and the fact, that the derivatives of the FT can be expressed as multiplication with polynomials.

That $\mathcal F$ is continuous follows:

> from the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma and the Fact, that $   \mathcal{S}( \mathbb R) \subset L^1( \mathbb R) $ and $\mathcal{S}( \mathbb R) \subset C_0( \mathbb R)$

Now my question here is, if any arguments can be simplifyed. Or if the continuity already follows from the continuity of $\mathcal{F}: L^1 \rightarrow C_0$.

For the proof of the automorphism property:

> The Plancherel theorem gives us an isomorphism $\mathcal F :L^2 \rightarrow L^2$. So we deduce that $\mathcal F$ is injective on $\mathcal S \subset L^2$.
>
> For the surjevtivity we use the inversion theorem which gives us a $\mathcal F^{-1}$ for all $f \in L^1$ where $\widehat f \in L^1$ (hence for all $\mathcal S$ functions).

At this point im not sure if my proof is 100% correct or if it could be simplyfied as well.

Comment: The injectivity argument is fine, and for the surjectivity you have to argue that the inverse Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is again a Schwartz function (which follows from 1). For (1) your argument looks OK, but continuity does not immediately follow from the continuity of the map from $L^1$ to continuous functions, because the topology of these spaces is very different from the topology on the Schwartz space.

Comment: I would completely ignore $L^1$ and $L^2$ and instead work exclusively with the Schwartz space. When proving $\mathcal{F}$ is continuous, the same proof tells you the inverse transform $\mathcal{G}$ is also continuous because all you have to do is change $i$ to $-i$. Finally you need the Fourier inversion for Schwartz functions, applied twice with $i$ and $-i$, so that $\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{G}=Id$ and $\mathcal{G}\circ\mathcal{F}=Id$ and you're done. As Lukas said continuity for the $L^1, C_0$ topologies is not enough because $\mathcal{S}$'s topology is much stronger.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I guess showing $\mathcal F \circ \mathcal G = Id$ is a simple symmetry argument.